# Equilateral pentagon inscribed in ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

Can someone tell me how to construct an **equilateral pentagon** (all its sides equal, not its angles) **inscribed in an ellipse** (with semi-axes 2 and 1) without approximations, with the **exact coordinates** of its vertices? (and if possible with a vertex at the point (0,1))

And with an equilateral polygon of n sides?

[something approximate of what I ask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzwRw.png)

Comment: Are you considering a coordinate geometry approach? It would be advisable to show what you have tried.

Comment: I have nothing clear. I tried to divide the 360 ​​degrees from the center by 5, as it is done to build the regular pentagon inscribed in a circle, but obviously it is not regular in the ellipse (not even equilateral). Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Please refer to the case for equilateral triangle [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717238).

Comment: A brute force approach would be to assign parameter values to points $B$ and $G$ and start writing down some equations (but I haven’t actually tried it myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the vertices of the pentagon be:
$$
P_1=(0,1),\ P_2=(x,y),\ P_3=(h,-k),\ P_4=(-h,-k),\ P_5=(-x,y)
$$
with $x,y,h,k$ all positive real numbers.
It is straightforward to write down four equations for them:
$$
\cases{
\strut x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 4 h^2\\ 
\strut (x - h)^2 + (y + k)^2 = 4 h^2\\ 
\strut x^2/4 + y^2 = 1\\
\strut h^2/4 + k^2 = 1
}
$$
I solved this system with Mathematica but the exact output is too large to be written here. Here's a numerical approximation:
$$
h = 0.84145,\ k = 0.907188,\ x = 1.62958,\ y = 0.579753.
$$

Comment: thank you very much!