# Locus of centroid of equilateral triangle inscribed in ellipse.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, locus, centroid

**Problem**

Find the locus of the centroid of an equilateral triangle inscribed in the ellipse $x^2 / a^2 + y^2 / b^2 = 1$

**My attempt**

I assumed 3 parametric points on ellipse P, Q and R. And assumed the centroid to be $G(h,k)$ As we know the formula for centroid (taking average of three coordinate assumed). Hence got the relation
$$
h= a(cos \theta_{1} + cos \theta_{2} + cos \theta_{3} )/3
$$
$$
k = b(sin \theta_{1} + sin \theta_{2} + sin \theta_{3} )/3
$$
Now I tried using formula for circumcentre and no matter whicher formula I used I used to get the same above equation. I tried writing equation of three sides and manually solving the centroid.

I also got an intuition that in an equilateral triangle all 4 centres are same. So centroid and circumcentre are same. So $ PG = QG = RG $. So I wrote down all the equation and equated them by comparing the LHS equation and RHS equation to get
$$
cos \theta_{1} = cos \theta_{2} = cos \theta_{3}
$$
$$
sin \theta_{1} = sin \theta_{2} = sin \theta_{3}
$$
which is obviously wrong as that would mean all the tree points assumed intersected into one single point.

Where exactly am I wrong? What did I miss that I had to think about which I didn't think. I am looking for some nice elegant human solution to this problem as I have seen a similar question in mathematical stack exchange in which they have directly solved equations and got very big equation for h and k.

Below I attach solution that is provided in textbook but in the textbook solution there is a formula written directly. If anyone could explain how I could prove the formula as no information is provided from where the formula came.[Solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8En3.jpg). [Solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpkBp.jpg)

Thanks for helping. I have been working on this for 3 days with no improvement. This is my first question on mathematics stack exchange so any comments on how should I state something is appreciated if I stated the wrong way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Now I tried using formula for circumcircle and no matter whicher formula I used I used to get the same above equation."? Which is the above equation? Are you saying that $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$ is always a circle?

Comment: @CalvinLin No by formula I meant circumcentre formula [here](https://byjus.com/maths/circumcenter-of-a-triangle/) sorry I wrote circumcircle by mistake and by above equation I am saying the h and k equation that I got.

Comment: The 3 points on ellipse P, Q and R are the corners of an _equilateral_ triangle. Could you pls show how you get point R starting from P and Q to achieve this?

Comment: @m-stgt I just assumed any three points on ellipse by parametric coordinate on Ellipse and assumed that three points form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Just consider P and Q quite close on the ellipse (close in relation to either axis), the distance of P and Q define the length of all sides of an **equilateral** triangle. Only on distinct ellipses R may "sit" on the circumerence of it -- unless your triangle defines the ellipse. But up to now I regarded the shape of the ellipse as independent.

Comment: Please refer to another post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717238/equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-an-ellipse/2717496#2717496).

Comment: @NgChungTak I appreciate the answer but I don't know much complex analysis besides if you see the solution images you will find that the textbook provided solved it without complex analysis. Any idea about how can I prove the formula that book provided?

Comment: Lookup Corollary 2 in the "Concyclic points" section of your textbook, you should find there the answer. Which book is that, by the way?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Arihant Skills in Mathematics for JEE Mains and Advance Coordinate Geometry by Dr. SK Goyal.In that this question is on page no. 551 subjective example 27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start with the coordinates of the vertices of the triangle as:
$$
A=(a\cos\alpha,b\sin\alpha),\quad
B=(a\cos\beta,b\sin\beta),\quad
C=(a\cos\gamma,b\sin\gamma),
$$
then you can find the coordinates of the circumcenter as the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of two sides.
The equation of the perpendicular bisector of side $AB$ is:
$$
y-\frac{b}{2} (\sin \alpha+b \sin\beta)
=\frac{a \cos \alpha-a \cos\beta}{b\sin\beta-b \sin \alpha}
\left(x-\frac{a}{2} (\cos \alpha+\cos \beta)\right)
$$
and you can find with the obvious substitutions the equation of the perpendicular bisector of side $BC$.
Solving the system of those two equations gives a quite long solution, which can be put into the simple form:
$$
x= \frac{a^2-b^2}{a}{ 
\cos \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}
\cos \frac{\alpha+\gamma}{2} 
\cos \frac{\beta+\gamma}{2}},
\quad
y= \frac{b^2-a^2}{b}{ 
\sin \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}
\sin \frac{\alpha+\gamma}{2} 
\sin \frac{\beta+\gamma}{2}}.
$$
Finally, using trig addition formulas, these can be rewritten in the form given by your textbook:
$$
\begin{align}
x&= \frac{a^2-b^2}{4a} 
[\cos \alpha+\cos\beta+\cos\gamma+\cos(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)],
\\ \ \\
y&= \frac{b^2-a^2}{4b} 
[\sin \alpha+\sin\beta+\sin\gamma-\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)].
\end{align}
$$

EDIT. In your textbook this formula is derived in a smarter way, from the property that the eccentric angles of the four intersection points between an ellipse and a circle add up to a multiple of $2\pi$. See pages 497-498.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried writing equation of perpendicular bisectors as well but because the calculation was going too long. I discontinued and tried if I can use some geometrical trickery. Thanks BTW!!